# Adding and Testing Compatibility of External Jar to Blackberry Project

Tags: blackberry, jar

I am a newbie at Blackberry development. I have Eclipse 3.5.1 and Blackberry JRE 4.7.0.
In my application, I added 2 external jars to my project and a properties file. I do not know for sure whether the jars I am trying to add and the webservices I am calling are compatible with Blackberry. I have to test that too.

When I tried running my project, I get - "Project has verification Error". Is it because I did not add the external jars correctly? Or is it because the jars may not be compatible with Blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a Third party librairy to a BlackBerry Project, you have to make sure it was compiled to work with BlackBerry First.

It needs to comply with J2ME and not J2SE.

The best is to compile the source yourself.

Comment: hi...i'm not sure i totally follow u...i dont have the src of the external jar. Can u explain in detail??